# android cannot be resolved or is not a field, android development

Tags: java, android

I am getting the above error with the below code, could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
ArrayAdapter<String>teamsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, teams);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> teamsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, teams);
                  ^ here you have dot in your declaration
```

Comment: Yeah that was the problem haha, should have seen that. Thanks! +1